# Adapter is not working properly in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am retrieving multiple images for multiple projects from firebase. The pictures are retrieved successfully from Firebase, but displaying the images, the Recycler Adapter shows one project's images in another project images and does not show the other project images. It happens initially for the first two projects but when I scroll up and down continuously it happens for different projects. I think maybe it is the size of the List I use to store the images.

```
private ArrayList<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<projects, ProjectViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<projects, ProjectViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProjectViewHolder projectViewHolder, int i, @NonNull projects projects)
            {
                Log.d("counting", String.valueOf(i));
                imagesRef = getRef(i).child("projectImageUrl");
                final int count =0 ;
                imagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {

                            imagesList.clear();
                            //Loop which I am running 
                            for(DataSnapshot postSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            String urls = postSnap.getValue().toString();
                            Log.d("NewImagesName", urls);
                            imagesList.add(urls);

                        }
                            //Recycler View
                            projectViewHolder.all_images.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1));
                            ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(getApplicationContext(), R.dimen.item_offset);
                            projectViewHolder.all_images.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
                            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()  , LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                            projectViewHolder.all_images.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            projectViewHolder.all_images.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


                            ImagesListAdapter imagesListAdapter = new ImagesListAdapter(getApplicationContext()  , imagesList , listener);
                            projectViewHolder.all_images.setAdapter(imagesListAdapter);
}

 public static  class ProjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        RecyclerView all_images ;
        public ProjectViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        all_images =(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagesRecyclerView) ;
    }
```

Here is Adapter

```
public class ImagesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesListAdapter.ImageViewHolder>
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> imagesList;

    IRecylerViewInterfaceListener clickListener ;

    public ImagesListAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<String> imagesList , IRecylerViewInterfaceListener clickListener)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.imagesList = imagesList;
        this.clickListener =clickListener;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {


        View  v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item , parent ,false);
        return  new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        String newCurrentImage =  imagesList.get(position);
        Log.d("currentImage",newCurrentImage);
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageView;
        final ProgressBar progressBar = holder.progressBar;
        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load(newCurrentImage).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource)
            {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource)
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
        }).into(imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
            return imagesList.size();
    }
```

Here what happens in Pictures
[image]

Here are the actual pictures
[image]

Comment: Do you need to write your own code to fetch the images and display them? Glide or Picasso do this very well and will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Yes because I have my own view which I want to show